# Get value of jQuery chosen element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to get value of jQuery Chosen element, but not getting anything. I think it could be because there is no value yet when I am searching for it, but not sure with that, because when the page loads, I can already see the value, which I need to get, on page. I've searched some threads here, but no solution worked for me. If anyone would know how to move with this, I would be so glad, thanks!
(I have to get value of `<span>` inside of `<a class="chosen-single">` ) and it's not because I don't have included jQuery library. I have, but I haven't pasted it here.

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/camm8yLj/

```
<a class="chosen-single" tabindex="-1">
<span>I/37 Chrudim - obchvat, úsek křiž. I/17 - Slatiňany</span>
</a>



$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.chosen-single').chosen().change(function () {
        $(this).find('span').each(function(){
            alert('Text : '+$(this).text());
            alert('Value : '+$(this).val());
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the text using `find` method.

`$('select').find('option:selected')` retrieves you all the options which are selected.

```
$('select').chosen();
$('select').change(function(){
    $(this).find('option:selected').each(function(){
    alert('value:'+$(this).val()+' text: '+$(this).text());
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Chosenify every multiple select DOM elements with class 'chosen'
    $('select.chosen').chosen();
    $('select.chosen').change(function(){
     $(this).find('option:selected').each(function(){
       alert('Value:'+$(this).val()+', Text: '+$(this).text());
      });
    });
});
```

```css
* { font-family: arial; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; }
h2 { font-size: 1.3em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.1.0/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>The Chosenified multiple &lt;select&gt;</h1>
<p>
    <select name="fruits" class="chosen" multiple style="width: 500px;">
        <option value="banane">Banane</option>
        <option value="pomme">Pomme</option>
        <option value="poire">Poire</option>
        <option value="ananas" selected>Ananas</option>
        <option value="kiwi" selected>Kiwi</option>
        <option value="goyave">Goyave</option>
        <option value="abricot">Abricot</option>
        <option value="fraise" selected>Fraise</option>
        <option value="framboise">Framboise</option>
        <option value="avocat" selected>Avocat</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Comment: and there don't have to be `chosen()` ?

Comment: What it is `chosen()` ?

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: `chosen()` is used with that `jQuery Chosen` library.

Comment: It is a select element ?

Comment: @HS1993  in each of your post when you added a jsfiddle you missed adding jquery library there. that is really annoying.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai well that's the thing! It works like a select element, and there also is select element, but `Chosen` replaces it with `div` and `ul li` elements, and also with elements which I have in question.

Comment: @HS1993, have a look to my answer.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai that works nice, but I need to get the value when the page loads, not on change..:/ that's the problem I have..

Comment: Ok, just replaced `.change()` with `.ready()` and it works how I need! Thank you!!